# How to create a list of n dictionaries

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and for practicing purposes I'm writing a script that reads a file (containing a graph in [Trivial Graph Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_Graph_Format)) and runs a couple of graph algorithms on the graph.

I thought about storing the graph in a list of n dictionaries, where n is the number of vertexes and all the edges of a vertex would be stored in a dictionary.

I tried this

```
edges = [{} for i in xrange(num_vertexes)]
for line in file:
    args = line.split(' ')
    vertex1 = int(args[0])
    vertex2 = int(args[1])
    label = int(args[2])
    edges[vertex1][vertex2] = label
```

but I'm getting this error for the last line:

> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you give an example of the data format you are looking to generate and the lines from the file that would generate this data format?

Comment: @DavidAlber That won't work all that well, since the inner dictionary will be copied by reference. `tst = [{}]*5; tst[0][1]=1;tst` will output `[{1: 1}, {1: 1}, {1: 1}, {1: 1}, {1: 1}]`.  What you can use instead is `[{} for x in xrange(num_vertexs)]`.

Comment: You may be interested in Guido's essay on [implementing graphs](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs.html)

Comment: Guys, please see dclements' answer. The problem turns out to be a really silly mistake I made in the code. I overlooked the fact that the first vertex (in the TGF data format) starts at 1, not 0. Hence the error. I'm sorry for bothering you all!

Comment: @jan zegan: thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `vertex1` is probably greater than `num_vertexes`.  Given that python indexes from 0 and the example on the wiki of the format goes from 1, the last line's vertex number is probably 1 higher than the length of the index (I'd need to see the file to know for sure, of course).  So in the python case `lst[0]` is the first element, and `lst[n-1]` is the last element where for the vertexes `1` is the first element and `n` is the last element.

So the fix here is to use `vertex1 = int(args[0])-1`

Comment: How silly of me! How could I have overlooked this? Using vertex1 = int(args[0])-1 solved it. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is somewhere with your data, add some validation to make sure your code doesn't choke on bad data.  Currently your code will fail if a line has non-numbers, less than three numbers, or if `vertex1 >= len(edges)`.

```
edges = [{} for i in xrange(num_vertexs)]
for line in file:
    args = line.split(' ')
    if len(args) >= 3:
        try:
            vertex1 = int(args[0])
            vertex2 = int(args[1])
            label = int(args[2])
            if vertex1 < len(edges):
                edges[vertex1][vertex2] = label
            else:
                # value for vertex1 is too large
                pass
        except ValueError:
            # you got some non-number data
            pass
    else:
        # you got a line with not enough data
        pass
```

Replace any of those `pass` statements with logging if needed (you can also remove the two `else` blocks if you don't intend to use them).